# Python3: sys.stdout for redirection - how to make created file's name variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I am redirecting my prints from a python script to a new file with this:

```
sys.stdout= open('/home/miriam/Dokumente/Atom/python/results.txt',"w")
```

instead of "results.txt", I want to name the file using a variable I read from stdin.
What I want is something like:

```
var=sys.argv[1]

sys.stdout= open('/home/miriam/Dokumente/Atom/python/var_results.txt',"w")
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried it with escaping with backslashes, but couldnt figure it out

This might be a duplicate, but I could not find anything so far. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So you format the string with your value then? `f'/home/.../{var}_results'` in 3.6 or `'/home/.../{}_results'.format(var)'` prior

Comment: Or even such a deprecated thing like `'/home/.../%s_results' % var` :)

Comment: You might also want to consider if you're redirecting the entire program - you might as well just pipe the stdout to a file when running, or look at the `contextlib.redirect_stdout` for just specific blocks instead of playing with `sys.stdout`

Comment: appearently, I am using 3.6, your solution worked, thank you! @JonClements if you want to post an answer I can upvote, do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply append the desired filename you got from `sys.argv` to the path:

```
Filename=sys.argv[1]
TheFile=open("path/to/your/file"+Filename,"w+")
```

Comment: In Python we usually use either string formatting or (for filesystem path stuff) `os.path.join()` instead of string concatenation. And the official naming convention is "all_lower_with_underscores" for variable names.